# Python issue with excel files. Columns are not written side by side

Tags: python, pandas

I have an issue with my code when trying to combine the data from multiple Excel files.
To be more explicit:
I have multiple Excel files, each file has the same format and only certain columns are filled with data in the first 28 rows.  For example in the first file columns filled are: D, E, F, X, Z. In the second file the columns filled are G, H, I, P and so on. I need to combine the columns from the files and paste them in the final template called template_sheet2 on the same rows, in the exact same position(column D should be written on column D, column E on column E and so on).
When running the below code, the columns from the first file are written in the first 28 rows as supposed, but from the second file and on are written below starting with the 29th row.

```
def import_files():
    template_sheet2 = template_wb["TT Matrix"]
    global dfs2
    dfs2 = []
    for excelfile in excelfiles:
        df2 = pd.read_excel(excelfile, sheet_name="TT Matrix", header=None, usecols=lambda col: col not in range(3) and col not in range(-4, 0))
        dfs2.append(df2)
    #concatenates the dataframe
    combined_df2 = pd.concat(dfs2, ignore_index=True, axis=1)
    #columns
    start_col = 4 #starting from column D
    matrix_cols = combined_df2.columns[start_col-4:-4] #get columns starting             from column D, dropping last 4 columns
    for j, col_name in enumerate(matrix_cols):
        col_letter = get_column_letter(j+start_col) #gets the column letter
        template_sheet2[col_letter + "1"].value = col_name #writes column headers

    row_index = 1
    for df in dfs2:
        df = df.iloc[:, :-4] #drop last 4 columns
        df = df.loc[:, df.notna().any()] #only select columns with non-null values
        matrix_cols = df.columns #update matrix_cols to include only selected columns
        for i, row in df.iterrows():
            for j, col_name in enumerate(matrix_cols):
                col_letter = get_column_letter(j+start_col) #gets the column letter
                template_sheet2[col_letter + str(row_index)].value = row[col_name] #copies the data
            row_index += 1
```

The code is longer, but I have added only the part related to my issue. The other code does not interfere with this sheet.
I need all the columns to be written on the first 28 rows. I have already tried to add axis=1 on  `df = df.loc[:, df.notna().any()]`, but that doesn't work and creates boolean errors.
[This is the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtrVS.png) and
[This is the actual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpeIl.png)
Any idea on how am I supposed to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing any of the data  which produces your problem. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Hello! sorry for the confusion, I have edited my initial message and added the desired output and the actual output

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: `combined_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)`

---

In my answer, I assume that each file contains a single sheet. If not, this code will load only the first sheet of each file.

I assume that you read in the data from excel files, and that you have a list of DataFrames, one for each file. Something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

n_files = 5
# Placeholder for the list of paths to your files
paths = [f'path_to_file{i}.xlsx' for i in range(n_files)]

# Load the data into a list of dataframes
dfs = [pd.read_excel(path) for path in paths]
```

I will here create some sample data to use as part of my answer, as I do not have access to your files. Here, I have four files, each with one to four columns, and each having 28 rows as specified in your question:

```py
import numpy as np

m_rows = 28

# create a random generator with a fixed seed for reproducibility
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)


columns = [
    ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    ['D'],
    ['E', 'F'],
    ['G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],
]

# create a pandas dataframe with random data and three columns
dfs = [pd.DataFrame(rng.random((m_rows, len(cols))), columns=cols) for cols in columns]
```

If all these assumptions hold, you can combine the content of your files with the following simple statement:

```py
combined_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for your reply. Each file contains multiple sheets, but I only get the sheet I need using: df2 = pd.read_excel(excelfile, sheet_name="TT Matrix", header=None, usecols=lambda col: col not in range(3) and col not in range(-4, 0)). I have tried your solution by using: combined_df2 = pd.concat(dfs2, axis=1) in the code, but I get the same output: the columns from the second file and on are being written bellow. I have edited my initial message with the desired output and the actual output. I'm a beginner and I'm not sure that my code is the best solution for my situation.

Comment: @Robertus The code in my answer should work. It is difficult to say what is going wrong without your data unfortunately.